# How can I target my mozilla profile on Mac OS the same way I'm targeting it in Windows?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a working python script that'll run perfectly on windows 10. It relies on python, selenium, and my current firefox profile. Here's the code i'm relying on to grab my profile in windows:

```
mozilla_profile = os.path.join(os.getenv('APPDATA'), r'Mozilla\Firefox')
mozilla_profile_ini = os.path.join(mozilla_profile, r'profiles.ini')
profile = configparser.ConfigParser()
profile.read(mozilla_profile_ini)
data_path = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(mozilla_profile, profile.get('Profile0', 'Path')))
```

I don't know how to make this work in Mac OS. I guess the os.path.join function doesn't work the same. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

On the line

```py
mozilla_profile = os.path.join(os.getenv('APPDATA'), r'Mozilla\Firefox')
```

You're getting the location of the user's `APPDATA` folder (this environment variable is set by Windows), then you're appending the `Mozilla\Firefox`. So, in the end you'll have the absolute path to the Mozilla profile directory.

OSX doesn't use `APPDATA`, so you'll need to find the absolute path to the user's Mozilla profile and use that instead.